# A Reporting engine similar to Windward

Tags: report, reporting, windward

I am looking out for Reporting Design solutions similar to Windward 
 - Designing templates in MS-Office instead of any IDE
 - Confidence that what you get is what you see during design..

Are there any other products in market giving these features?

Comment: Hi; I'm the CTO at Windward. Can you please list why Windward was not acceptable to you? Thanks - dave

Answer (score -1):

If i understand correctly, you want to design a report inside an Office product (most likely Excel) and get WYSIWYG capabilities, i don't know if the product you mention offers this (WYSIWYG), but on Excel is difficult to get pixel perfect reports, so you may want to consider using a reporting tool with a built in designer, like [DBxtra](http://www.dbxtra.com/) which is easy to use given that you can create a report with pure drag and drop.